# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'fillpoly' how to solve this

Tags: opencv, python

1
I'm getting the error instead of installing all the dependencies like python3.6.2, numpy, opencv, open-contrib-python.
2. **ERROR**-

```
    File "lane.py", line 23, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("result", region_of_interest(canny))
  File "lane.py", line 15, in region_of_interest
    cv2.fillpoly(mask, polygons, 255)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'fillpoly'
```

3**SOURCE CODE**-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def canny(image):
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(lane_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
     blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
     canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
     return canny

def region_of_interest(image):
    height = image.shape[0]
    polygons= np.array([(200, height), (1100, height), (550, 250)])
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.fillpoly(mask, polygons, 255)
    return mask


image = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
lane_image = np.copy(image)
canny = canny(lane_image)

cv2.imshow("result", region_of_interest(canny))
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: It is fillPoly(), not fillpoly(). OpenCV is very particular about case in spelling of methods.

Comment: @fmw42  Thank you so much.